# 雛たちとはなんの意味でしょうか？

Tags: meaning, usage, word-usage, song-lyrics

中島みゆきさんの「銀の龍の背に乗って」の歌詞の中、こういう言葉が見つかります：

> まだ飛べない**雛たち**みたいに

「雛たち」とはなんですか。「雛形」の意味しますか、ここで「まだ飛べないちっちゃい龍」のことを指しているのですか。

Comment: Is there a reason you think it's something other than the dictionary definition of 雛?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I though 雛たち was gonna be one word, but didn't find any dictionary entries for "雛たち". Now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「雛たち**みたい**に」はこれが比喩であることを示しています。通常、雛（ひな）は鳥の子どもを指しますが、龍が登場している文脈では、龍の子どもの比喩だとしてでもおかしくはありません。これはおそらく、龍と鳥がある程度似ている（どちらも飛ぶ）ことが理由だと思います。これに対し、「鯨の雛」は比喩だと仮定してもやや不自然に感じられます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。なぜか「雛たち」が単体の単語だと思ってました。辞書に定義なんて見つかりませんので、ここで質問を聞き投げたいと思いました。